# Sometimes JavaScript doesn't find my function unless I make the first letter capital

Tags: javascript

Sometimes when I add a new function to my JavaScript script (or sometimes it even does it with old functions that previously worked!) it gives me an error that says

> include_moduleingabe.php:1537 Uncaught ReferenceError: (function name) is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (include_moduleingabe.php:1537)

I always try everything I can think of: Changing the name to something (usually `test()`), uncommenting all code in case it's faulty and only put a `console.log("test");` in it, checking if I called it under the right name, copy and pasting the name to make SURE there's no spelling errors. And lately I've been just keeping the name of the function, except changing the first letter to a capital in both the function definition and the call. Because sometimes, not always, but sometimes that works for some reason.

Here's my recent example. This is the original, before changing the function name

```
function verwendbarkeit() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="studiengang" id="weitererStudiengang2Wahlmodul" value="weiterer Studiengang 2 (Wahlmodul)" onclick="verwendbarkeit()">
```

Console output:

> Uncaught TypeError: verwendbarkeit is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick (include_moduleingabe.php:1537)

Function (after changing first letter to capital)

```
function Verwendbarkeit() { 
  console.log("test");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="studiengang" id="weitererStudiengang2Wahlmodul" value="weiterer Studiengang 2 (Wahlmodul)" onclick="Verwendbarkeit()">
```

Console output:

```
test
```

This is beyond frustrating. Can anyone explain to me what's going on, why this is happen? And why it's only sometimes? I usually prefer to start my functions with a lowercase letter and then use camelCase, but this is practically making it impossible!

Comment: Hard to say without a [MCVE] that illustrates the issue, but I bet you could solve it by properly attaching the handler using Javascript, rather than using an inline HTML attribute (look up `addEventListener`)

Comment: It definitely **won't** be down to changing the capitalization. Functions used in `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers have to be globals. It's one of several reasons not to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. Also note that parsing errors in your script may prevent functions getting created (even errors in code completely separate from the function).

Comment: As the previous comments have stated this won't be due to the capitalisation. My guess would be that you're using the function name as a variable somewhere else and have therefore over-written the original function reference

Comment: Since you are using js alongside php, it seems to me the problem is more likely on php side. I suggest you look through the served html, which is generated by php, and see if anything wrong in the generated content.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have an HTML with the same `id` and `name` as the function, could that be the problem?

Comment: The problem could be with HTML DOM are you fetching any HTML using from PHP Server or something like that?

Comment: Yes it **does** matter, when the browser automatically creates global objects based on element ids, and therefor _overwrites_ the function.

Comment: @04FS Okay then that must've been it! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had an HTML element of the same ID as the name of the function. HTML ID's overwrite JavaScript functions.